# How to target object method by it name?

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to target a object method by passing it's name to a function as an argument.

```
var obj = {
    key1: "more",
    target: function()
    {
      return obj.key1 + "DATA"; // cause     key2 : obj.key1 + 'MORE',    is not working (cause this doesn't exist jet)
    },
    func: function(toReplace)
    {
      // I want target obj.target (toREplace function argument tell us what obj key to target) so I can... for example .replace() some of it value, but
      //obj[toReplace] = obj[toReplace].replace('DATA', 'VARIABLES'); // is not working...
      obj.toReplace() = obj.toReplace().replace('DATA', 'VARIABLES'); // is not working either...
    }
};

console.log(obj.target()); // "moreDATA" - ok
obj.func('target');
console.log(obj.target()); // should be "moreVARIABLES"
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this technique that might be better done another way?

Comment: I need to target the specific field (key-method) of obj by referencing it in a function argument. I will gladly hear about another method to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `"DATA"` into a field of `obj`, and used that field in `target`, then you could change the value of that field to get the desired behavior.

Something like this:

```
var obj = {
    key1: "more",
    target_key2: "DATA",
    target: function()
    {
      return this.key1 + this.target_key2;
    },
    func: function(toReplace)
    {
      this[toReplace+"_key2"] = 'VARIABLES';
    }
};

console.log(obj.target());
obj.func('target');
console.log(obj.target());
```

Comment: Yea I know but I need it to be modified first. So I use method to do that and I have problem later on when try to target this method (to get modified value, and replace some of it's content).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to achieve what you want to achieve. But I have written a snippet which given you this functionality -

```
var obj = {
    key1: "more",
    target: function()
    {
      return obj.key1 + "DATA";
    },
    func: function(toReplace)
    {
      obj.tmp=toReplace; // tmp holds the reference to the original target function
      obj.target=function() // swapping obj.target with this new function
      {
        return obj.tmp().replace('DATA', 'VARIABLES'); // call the cached function and do the replace
      }
    }
};

console.log(obj.target()); // "moreDATA"
obj.func(obj.target);      // instead of "target" you will have to send the target function
console.log(obj.target()); // it is "moreVARIABLES"
```